# File is not saved in the bucket even if I get the upload success message

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-8, laravel-9

I'm having a problem storing images in the created bucket. I get the image uploaded correctly message but going to see the bucket no image is stored. After creating the bucket and updating the variables in the .env file shown below

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

AWS_DEFAULT_REGION

AWS_BUCKET

I wrote the following code shown below:

**Route:**

```
Route::get('image-upload', [ ImageUploadController::class, 'imageUpload' ])->name('image.upload');
Route::post('image-upload', [ ImageUploadController::class, 'imageUploadPost' ])->name('image.upload.post');
```

**Controller:**

```
 public function imageUploadPost(Request $request)
    {        
        $request->validate([
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);
    
    $file = $request->file('image');
    $name = 'imgname.jpg';
    $filePath = 'images/' . $name;
    Storage::disk('s3')->put($filePath, file_get_contents($file));

        return back()
            ->with('success','You have successfully upload image.');

    }
```

**View:**

```
<x-layout>


    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </div>
    <img src="{{ Session::get('image') }}">
    @endif

    @if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
    @endif

    <form action="{{ route('image.upload.post') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>

</x-layout>
```

Can you kindly help me? I've been trying for several hours but I don't get any results.

The only thing I see is that if I try to print via a dd `Storage::disk('s3')->put($filePath, file_get_contents($file));`, i.e.

`dd( Storage::disk('s3')->put($filePath, file_get_contents($file)))` I get **false**.

Can this help?

Comment: Hello @maurice
Can you try this
`Storage::disk('s3')->put($filePath, file_get_contents($file),'public-read');`

Comment: One more thing can you please define a new variable in the env file and set it to false
`AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false`

Comment: @LokendraSinghPanwar tried but nothing happens, everything remains as before